# Creating a dynamically growing table in HTML

Tags: html, dynamic, html-table

I am super new to HTML, so I am not sure if I need to use a Javascript function to implement this, or how to even begin. I would like to create a table that grows and shrinks based on the data received. I know that HTML has a table tag, and I have been playing around with it, but I don't know how to make it create cells based on varying data.

Comment: Where is your dynamic content coming from?

Comment: The data is coming from a backend server in JSON. I need to parse it some how, then populate the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you using to populate your data? As far as I know HTML5 has the same tags for the table manipulation. So if you are using PHP or .NET, you usually have something like a loop that creates as many rows as you need with the data from the database or other data source. 
It may look something like that

declare variable to hold table data

add `<table>` tag

do your loop that adds rows

add `</table>` tag

post the variable to some place on your page to display the table.

Comment: The data is coming from a backend server in JSON. I need to parse it some how, then populate the table.

Comment: use JSON.parse for that purpose (you may need an additional plug-in to be able to do that). Then in Javascript, you can declare a variable to hold table data, and do a loop that would use your JSON data to populate the rows. Finally, use JQuery to populate some div on your page with the contents of the variable you created...would be something like $('#div').html(variable);